# Landau notation (ide) tools support

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans, intellij-idea, big-o

It is good idea to have impotant information during developing like Landau notation to know functions's time costs. So it should be documented in sources isn't it?

I'm looking for tools that can calculate it.

Comment: Interesting... I don't know of any tools that can calculate the Big-O of a piece of code. Not sure such things exist (or are even possible), but if there are, I'd be interested to see them.

Comment: For example, if language designers will document big-0 for atomic operations it might be possible.
Or if you have method with some params (collections) than unit test can be run and log duration of method execution with different collection length. That's how O can be calculated.

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, the asymptotic complexity of an arbitrary algorithm is undecidable, by [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

But in practice, you can often make a good guess by repeatedly running the algorithm on various inputs (of sizes spanning several orders of magnitude), recording actual CPU time, and fitting a curve. (You should throw out data points with very short runtimes, since these will be dominated by noise. Also, on JITed runtimes like the Java Virtual Machine, make sure to run the function for a while before starting the timing, to make sure the VM has warmed up.)